# preg_replace_callback returns 'Array'

Tags: php, templates, preg-replace-callback

It's templater:

```
Class View {

    public static function ShowStaticPage($way) {
        global $cfg;

        ob_start(); 

        include self::Get($way);

        return ob_get_clean();  
    }

    public static function getURL() {
        global $cfg;

        return empty($cfg['theme']) ? ROOT.'templates/Bootstrap/' : ROOT.'templates/'.$cfg['theme'].'/' ;
    }

    public static function getContent($file) {
        global $cfg;

        $theme_dir = self::getURL();
        $input = file_get_contents($theme_dir.$file.'.tpl');

        $regex_lng = "/\{(lng)\:((?:[0-9a-zA-Z\/]+))\}/";
        $regex_tpl = "/\{(tpl)\:((?:[0-9a-zA-Z\/]+))\}/";

        $input = preg_replace_callback($regex_lng, 'self::lng', $input);
        $input = preg_replace_callback($regex_tpl, 'self::getContent', $input);

        return $input;
    }

    public static function lng($caller) {
        global $cfg, $lng;

        return sprintf("%s",$lng[$param]);
    }

}
```

In input files I have {tpl:tplfold1/sometplnamethere} and {lng:login} which I need to replace on parsing. But when I'm trying to load tpl out of another it gives the name of tpl "Array.tpl". What I'm doing wrong? I know, that preg_replace_callback gives array but how to get the name? Or just iterate every name with 'getContent'?

Comment: do a var_dump of the value passed into your callback functions. You would likely see that the callback function is passed in an *array* of matches containing each grouped item from the regex, not a string. In your case it would probably be something like `['tpl','tplfold1/sometplnamethere']` If you had error reporting turned on, you would also likely see an "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: That is what it gives: http://prntscr.com/6crj3m
Maybe I'm too stupid, sorry =)

Comment: I was just going based off the documentation. It specifically says the callback should be defined as `string handler ( array $matches )`. I'll run a test right now.

Comment: My test shows an array. I see what you are doing wrong from what I suggested. I was saying call var_dump on the value passed in, not the return from `preg_replace_callback`. Do a `var_dump($file);` inside `getContent` and `var_dump($caller);` inside of `lng` to see your arguments. You should see arrays.

Comment: xDD Doesnt work: http://prntscr.com/6crzq6

Comment: Oooops sorry, yes, sure, it even doesnt have to work =) So what I need to do now with this arrays? I just want to replace something, why in php everything is so hard? In java it's replaceAll and nothing else =_=

Comment: I was just trying to show you want the value `preg_replace_callback` passes into your callback functions. I would assume you want key `[2]` in both functions. so `$file[2]` and `$caller[2]`.

Comment: Try this: at the top of `getContent()` add `$file = is_array($file)?$file[2]:$file;` which will get the value under the second if an array was passed in or itself if not an array. And in `lng()` I'm assuming `$param` should really be `$caller[2]` instead because `$param` is not defined.

Comment: And if it's more than one pare? Like file.tpl: {tpl:somefile}, somefile.tpl: {tpl:someotherfile}, someotherfile.tpl: {tpl:anotherfile}, anotherfile.tpl etc?
What would happen then? And I have a question: why this stupid function just cant foreach all that it found and then call an individual function for every of functions? 
Sry for English =)

Comment: It does essentially foreach over each match. Regular expressions have groups though (using parenthesis) and so what gets passed in is an array where key 0 is the whole match and subsequent values are the other groups. It still calls the callback function once for each match found. I can't imagine ANY other language doing something different as they should all support regex grouping and arrays are pretty much the only way to pass in multiple values to a single argument. Another options is you could use just preg_match_all and loop over the results yourself calling a callback.

Comment: You could also do an anonymous function within preg_replace_callback with an argument. The values caught by the regex is placed into that argument as an array, and just filter them out that way.

Comment: Thank u for $file = is_array($file)?$file[2]:$file;! How can I add you some reputation or like add "plus" to your answer?